# unable to install eucalyptus in centos 7.9

Tags: linux, cloud, repository, centos7, eucalyptus

I just followed fast installation eucalyptus guide but one of the ansible playbook thrown error with unable to reach "midonet" repository. Can some help me on the alternative methods on this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the rpms from here:

https://github.com/tsew/midonet