# Can't reach builds.midonet.org when installing Eucalyptus

Tags: eucalyptus

As the subject says, I am doing the local installing running `bash <(curl -Ls https://get.eucalyptus.cloud)` but I am getting the following errors:

```
[Ansible] Installing Eucalyptus ansible package
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
http://builds.midonet.org/midonet-5.2/stable/el7/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://builds.midonet.org/midonet-5.2/stable/el7/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Connection timed out after 30000 milliseconds')
Trying other mirror.
http://builds.midonet.org/midonet-5.2/stable/el7/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://builds.midonet.org/midonet-5.2/stable/el7/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Connection timed out after 30002 milliseconds')http://builds.midonet.org/midonet-5.2/stable/el7/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://builds.midonet.org/midonet-5.2/stable/el7/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds')
Trying other mirror.
```

It says it is trying other mirror but it doesn't appear that way.

I tried to ping the domain but no response and navigating to the root domain via a web browser fails to show anything.  Is this something on my side or is the host really down?

This is my first time looking at Eucalyptus.cloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a webserver laying around

```
---
- name: make sure destination dir exists
  file:
    path: '/tmp/midonet/'
    state: directory
  tags:
    - localinstall

- name: download a copy of the packages that should have been in the midonet repo
  get_url:
    url: 'http://pxe.server.lan/packages/midonet/{{ item }}'
    dest: '/tmp/midonet/'
  with_items:
      - libzookeeper-3.4.8-4.x86_64.rpm
      - libzookeeper-devel-3.4.8-4.x86_64.rpm
      - lldpd-0.9.5-2.1.x86_64.rpm
      - lldpd-debuginfo-0.9.5-2.1.x86_64.rpm
      - lldpd-devel-0.9.5-2.1.x86_64.rpm
      - midolman-5.2.2-1.0.el7.noarch.rpm
      - midonet-cluster-5.2.2-1.0.el7.noarch.rpm
      - midonet-selinux-1.0-2.el7.centos.noarch.rpm
      - midonet-tools-5.2.2-1.0.el7.noarch.rpm
      - python-midonetclient-5.2.2-1.0.el7.noarch.rpm
      - python-zookeeper-3.4.8-4.x86_64.rpm
      - quagga-0.99.23-0.el7.midokura.x86_64.rpm
      - zkdump-1.05-1.noarch.rpm
      - zkpython-3.4.5-2.x86_64.rpm
      - zookeeper-3.4.8-4.x86_64.rpm
      - zookeeper-debuginfo-3.4.8-4.x86_64.rpm
      - zookeeper-lib-3.4.5-1.x86_64.rpm
  register: lidownlowd
  retries: 3
  delay: 3
  until: lidownlowd is not failed
  tags:
    - localinstall

- name: localinstall all packages from midonet repo
  shell: yum -y localinstall *.rpm
  args:
    chdir: '/tmp/midonet/'
```

Comment: also disable `eucalyptus-ansible/roles/common/files/midonet.repo` and `eucalyptus-ansible/roles/common/files/midonet-misc.repo`

Comment: This was a while ago for me but I think I did something similar.  Thanks for posting the solution.

Answer (score 1):

please refer to [unable to install eucalyptus in centos 7.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72921406/unable-to-install-eucalyptus-in-centos-7-9)

i'll give it a go and let you know the outcome